# From what place a databse should be accessed according to MVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model

I have a problem to understand how to properly download data from a database to my model object according to MVC architecture in my app.

Here is how the app looks like:

```
                 / NavigationController -> ViewController -> ...
TabBarController - NavigationController -> ViewController -> ...
                 \ NavigationController -> ViewController -> ...
```

So `TabBarController` is initial controller with 3 tabs. Under each tab there is a chain of `UIViewController` embedded in a `NavigationController`. Each View controlled by particular `UIViewController` is displaying data from database. These data are updated quite often so I need to download them from database periodically.

Then I have a model object. In my app I have only this one model object so all `UIViewController` have access to the same model object (I know each `UIViewController` should have its own model object but I have reasons to do that in this way).

As I understand MVC, the communication should be like this:

- when a View must be updated, `UIViewController` sends a request for data to a model object
- model object gets the data from a source
- when the data are updated, model object sends information to a `UIViewController`
- `UIViewController` updates data from a model object to a View

This should be OK. But I am not sure where should be placed a `DatabaseController` which connects to a database and sends requests to it. This should be separated controller and model object must have a reference to it because he needs to tell him that he needs update its data.

I have found some blog with information that the `DatabaseController` should be created inside the model object and separated from model object code using a category. My opinion is that this is bad idea because it breakes MVC architecture.

What do you think? What is the best solution for placing `DatabaseController` in the app? Should I put it into the object model or outside...

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Objective-C before, but in general OOP, the code to access the DB should definitely be placed in a single, separate place - among other things, this makes it mush easier to maintain and modify the code to access the DB in the future, and makes code clearer in general.

A well-known and widely used approach is the [**Data Access Object (DAO)**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-persistence/dao-design-pattern.html) pattern, which allows you to abstract the persistence details of your application from the rest of the logic.
The [**Repository**](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern is also used very often for this purpose.

In your case, if you have a *model* class called `Thing`, you'd create a `ThingDAO`, with methods such as `getAllThings()`, `getThingById(id)`, `updateThing(thing)`, `deleteThing(id)`, etc.
Then you can call this object from your `Controller`, or better in my opinion, from your model class(es).

---

You may think that, as we add another layer, "*it breakes MVC architecture*" - in my opinion, actually the DAO layer is a part of the model. I think your concept of *model* is probably not quite right - bear in mind that the model is not one class, but a group of (potentially thousands of) classes. In a big app, your model would contain things like Entities, DAOs, EventListeners, Handlers, Managers, Commands, Transformers, Helpers, and many other things...

Comment: If I use DAO pattern, my Controller call these methods from ThingDAO. ThingDAO asks DatabaseController for new data. When the DatabaseController returns data, ThinkDAO save data to the Thing and Thing will notify the Controller that it has new data. Controller gets data from Thing. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielH: yes, something like that. Not sure what you mean with "*Thing will notify the Controller that it has new data*". I'd say the `ThingDAO` return 1 or more `Thing` objects to the `Controller`, and the `Controller` gets data from them. Also not sure about the role of the `DatabaseController` - probably these are things quite specific  to objective-c? Apart from those details, yes, I think you got it :)

Comment: I want to update my Views only if data have chaged. So if I download data from DB and send them to the Thing, Thing will check if the data have changed or are the same. If data have changed, it will trigger event "DataChanged" and Controller will handle this event - gets data and updates View. Next thing is that downloading data is asyn. operation in my case so it should be solved with events and not waiting for method to return data...

Answer (score 0):

Data access, and more, like business logic should be part of the model, and I'll try to explain why:

- putting more and more of the application logic into the model component leads to the fat models, skinny controllers paradigm
- fat model, skinny paradigm leads to unit-testable code, as controllers are not very suitable for unit testing
- this approach also increases the reusability of your components, as it's unlikely you'll reuse controllers (most of the controllers are application-targeted)

Of course this applies to MVC, however as this pattern is heavily used in the iOS development, it makes sense to primary focus on it.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to move towards MVOC architecture where O represents Others. Others would be a layer that does not fit in either of M, V, or C. Here O would be your network layer. A singleton object that your controller calls to fetch data and gets a filled model object in return.

Comment: The idea of another layer for the DB access is correct, but that *MVOC* you came up with is one of the funniest inventions I heard of lately :)